# android fragment can't set button text

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I have an odd problem. I have setup fragments and I am loading with volley database, details into the fragment. However, when I try to set the data I am getting from json into the buttons and textview, it does not work. Also it isn't showing any errors. So I am logging the output of one of the buttons and getting the following log:

```
D/Homepage points: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{98f2495 VFED..C.. ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0c00a0 app:id/pointsNr}
```

I have no idea what this means. Below is my post request to get the items from the database and populate the buttons

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, POST_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Log.d("Homepage RESPONSE", response);

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            String getusername = jsonResponse.getString("username");
                            String getfollowers = jsonResponse.getString("followers");
                            String getdonate = jsonResponse.getString("collected");
                            String gettotalkm = jsonResponse.getString("total_km");
                            String getpoints = jsonResponse.getString("points");


                            System.out.println("Homepage Username: " + getusername);

                            username.setText("Welkom " + getusername);
                            followersNr.setText(getfollowers);
                            donatedNr.setText(getdonate);
                            totalKmNr.setText(gettotalkm);
                            pointsNr.setText(getpoints);

                            Log.d("Homepage points raw", "" + getpoints);
                            Log.d("Homepage points", ""+pointsNr);



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        //Intent i = new Intent(login.this, login.class);

                        // startActivity(i);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                      //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(POST_USEREMAIL, emailUser);

                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
```

When I run this on another activity which is not a fragment, it does what it supposed to do. But in the fragment everything seems to be different.

Below is the xml of the fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.befitdonate.befitdonate.HomePage">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="@string/user"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/frontheader"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"    />




        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.14"
            android:columnCount="1"

            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/followersNr"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:background="@drawable/polygon"


                    />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/donatedNr"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:background="@drawable/polygon"

                    />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/totalKmNr"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:background="@drawable/polygon"

                    />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/pointsNr"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:background="@drawable/polygon"

                    />
                <Space
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>



        </GridLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/followersLink"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:text="Volgers"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="@color/colorLightBlue"



                />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/donatedLink"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:text="Gedoneerd"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="@color/colorLightBlue"

                />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/totalKmLink"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:text="Total Km"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="@color/colorLightBlue"

                />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/pointsLink"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:text="Punten"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="@color/colorLightBlue"

                />
            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I need to build a lot of fragments, so I would really like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

This is the complete code for more clarification

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class HomePage extends Fragment {


    TextView username;
    Button followersNr;
    Button donatedNr;
    Button totalKmNr;
    Button pointsNr;
    Button followersText;
    Button donatedText;
    Button totalKmText;
    Button pointsText;

    private SharedPreferences preferenceSettings;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor preferenceEditor;
    private static final int PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE = 0;
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "UserDetails";

    String emailUser;

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String POST_USEREMAIL = "username";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        preferenceSettings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PREFERENCE_MODE_PRIVATE);
        preferenceEditor = preferenceSettings.edit();
        emailUser = preferenceSettings.getString("Email", null);
        Log.d("Saved user email:", "" + emailUser);



        }




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view =  lf.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);
        FrameLayout ll = (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);

        username = (TextView) ll.findViewById(R.id.username);
        followersNr = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.followersNr);
        donatedNr = (Button)ll.findViewById(R.id.donatedNr);
        totalKmNr = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.totalKmNr);
        pointsNr = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.pointsNr);
        followersText = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.followersNr);
        donatedText = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.donatedLink);
        totalKmText = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.totalKmLink);
        pointsText = (Button) ll.findViewById(R.id.pointsLink);

        homePageDetails();

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);
    }





    ////////////////////////// get user details //////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void homePageDetails() {

        Log.d("Homepage USEREMAIL", " " + emailUser);
        String POST_URL = "";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, POST_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Log.d("Homepage RESPONSE", response);

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            String getusername = jsonResponse.getString("username");
                            String getfollowers = jsonResponse.getString("followers");
                            String getdonate = jsonResponse.getString("collected");
                            String gettotalkm = jsonResponse.getString("total_km");
                            String getpoints = jsonResponse.getString("points");


                            System.out.println("Homepage Username: " + getusername);

                            username.setText("Welkom " + getusername);
                            followersNr.setText(getfollowers);
                            donatedNr.setText(getdonate);
                            totalKmNr.setText(gettotalkm);
                            pointsNr.setText(getpoints);

                            Log.d("Homepage points raw", "" + getpoints);
                            Log.d("Homepage points", ""+pointsNr);



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        //Intent i = new Intent(login.this, login.class);

                        // startActivity(i);

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                      //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put(POST_USEREMAIL, emailUser);

                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Where are you making the stringRequest call at? Fragments views cannot be accessed or changed until after the view is created (onViewCreated event or onActivityAttached event). Basically, if it's not attached to an activity the view will not have been created and you won't be able to access the views. I'm not sure if that's your issue without more context unfortunately.

Comment: i was just wondering that. i was calling it from the oncreate and figured that it might execute the request before the oncreateview. So i am testing that now.

Comment: Yep that will be your issue. You'll need to do it after the layout inflater. I generally will do that type of logic in the @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)  Your other option is to do it in the onCreate and save the response in an object and only set the text once the view is created. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html has the lifecycle it's a pretty good explanation of how it all works.

Comment: when i will try the @Override public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) and see if that might be working.

Comment: Also calling the method from onViewCreated did not work

Comment: Why are you inflating fragment_home_page everywhere on your onCreateView()??

Comment: What sunil said - when you inflate it recreates the view. So you're setting your references to objects and then recreating the view which will have different views. Inflate once set your variables. And go from there but do not inflate again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your onCreateView to this..

```
LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View view =  lf.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);

            username = (TextView) view .findViewById(R.id.username);
            followersNr = (Button) view .findViewById(R.id.followersNr);
            donatedNr = (Button)view .findViewById(R.id.donatedNr);
            totalKmNr = (Button) view .findViewById(R.id.totalKmNr);
            pointsNr = (Button) view .findViewById(R.id.pointsNr);
            followersText = (Button) view .findViewById(R.id.followersNr);
            donatedText = (Button) view .findViewById(R.id.donatedLink);
            totalKmText = (Button) view .findViewById(R.id.totalKmLink);
            pointsText = (Button) view .findViewById(R.id.pointsLink);

            homePageDetails();

            return view ;
```